# Android application for vehicle tracking using GPS

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to develop an android application for vehicle tracking using GPS signals only. It will have two components:

1. An android device with android application that will be in the vehicle to be tracked. It will send lat and long of the device using text message after the interval of 1 minute.
2. The second component will be an android device where the message will be delivered and the message will be then read by an android application which will scan the message for lat and long. Once the lat and long are found the location will be plotted on some offline map.

I have completed the first component and i am stuck with the plotting part. How can i build an app that can plot the coordinates received in a text messages.
Can I use the google maps API, or there is something better for this? I have been searching for days but with no luck. Please help

Answer (score 1):

I will tell u how to send the text message to send current location latitude and longitude

In your android manifest allow these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then this will be your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS = 0;
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    Button sendBtn;

    String phoneNo = "+923044075653";

    String message;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        getLastLocation();
        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            }
        });



    }
    protected void sendSMSMessage() {







        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION
        );
    }

    private boolean isLocationEnabled() {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        );
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SEND_SMS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getLastLocation();
                } else {
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                }
            }


        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            getLastLocation();
        }

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void getLastLocation(){
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {
                mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(
                        new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                                Location location = task.getResult();
                                if (location == null) {
                                    requestNewLocationData();
                                } else {

                                    message="http://maps.google.com?q="+location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions();
        }


    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private void requestNewLocationData(){

        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(0);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(0);
        mLocationRequest.setNumUpdates(1);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(
                mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
                Looper.myLooper()
        );

    }

    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            Location mLastLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
            message="http://maps.google.com?q="+mLastLocation.getLatitude()+","+mLastLocation.getLongitude();
        }
    };
```

According to this code by clicking on button a text message will be sent to your mobile network

and in your gradle file include these libraries

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. But as I said in my post I have already developed this. I want to know how to develop the second component